# ssh, samba, microserv and apache not working after IP change

Tags: networking, server, netplan

I installed Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS and under DHCP address 192.168.0.10 installed OpenSSH, LAMP, Samba, Webmin. I changed netplan to manual IP 192.168.0.10, and everything worked fine, but when I changed the IP to 192.168.0.9 there is no response from any server (ssh, LAMP, Samba...). If I change back the IP everything works again.

UFW status is inactive. Any idea why the server is not accessable?

Comment: Which device, server or client, does the IP (`192.168.0.9` or `192.168.0.10`) belongs to?

Comment: The address of the server is 192.168.0.10 but if i change it to 192.168.0.9 than nothing is accessible any more

Comment: Don't ever set a static ip-address that is included in a dhcp-range. You risk that it is given to / in use by another device.

Comment: Thank you Soren, after so many years in IT I did not checked the dhcp range and sinned against dhcp server, entered to his territory and been sentenced to chase shadows of lost ports thru hall night.

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell: change IPs in your config files from `.10` to `.9`.

Step-by-step tutorial (do this in any config files originally using `.10`):

1. Run `nano <filename>` (or `sudo nano <filename>` if it needs root permissions to edit)
2. Find `192.168.0.10` and replace them with `192.168.0.9`.
3. Restart the related services

Comment: Madmin@ubunas:/$ sudo grep -r 192.168.0.10 *
etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml:            addresses: ['192.168.0.10/24']

The IP is only in netplan config

Comment: netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:445             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN                                 699/smbd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:139             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN                                 699/smbd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN                                 756/perl
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN                                 1012/sshd: /usr/sbi

Comment: server is listening on all IP-s but not "hearing"

Comment: I can ping it from other computer (on interface 192.168.0.9) but the ports are not responding...

Answer (score 0):

I made a big mistake, I did not check if IP .9 is free, so I poked into an already used IP. That was causing the problem.... So people, if you can not access your ports, take a look for IP conflicts.